# Choose all variables after $var_no_N

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I want to choose all or a set of variables that occurs after N number of variables.

Eg: I have a file with multiple lines which are comma separated. How do I choose all variables that come after variable no. 4 and output them to another file?

I have a file `test1.txt`:

```
A, B, C, D, E    
A, B, C, D, E, F, G    
A, B, C, D
```

And want the below output in `output.txt`:

```
E    
E, F, G  
(Nothing), as Line 3 had only 4 variables.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `cut`:

```
cut -d, -f5- test1.txt > output.txt
```

Explanation:
- cut explodes every line in blocks based on the `-d` parameter. In our case, the comma.
- with `-f` we indicate which blocks have to printed. `-f1` would print the first, `-f-3` would print the three first ones. With `-f5-` you print from the 5th to the end.

Comment: Thanks, @sputnick, I did not know `cut` accepted the sentence like this.

Comment: @sputnick, thanks a lot.. I was looking exactly for soemthing like this !

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
sed -e '/^\([^,]*,\s*\)\{4\}/!d;s/^\([^,]*,\s*\)\{4\}//' test1.txt
```

Edit: Just looked at it and realized it can be simplified (forgot about the t branch command):

```
sed -e 's/^\([^,]*,\)\{4\}//;tX;d;b;:X;s/^\s*//' test1.txt
```

And to isolate one value (17th in this case) instead of running to the end of the line:

```
sed -e 's/^\([^,]*,\)\{16\}//;tX;d;b;:X;s/^\s*\([^,]*\).*/\1/' test1.txt
```

Comment: @Williams, the sed thing didn't work.... do I need to add something else in there ?

Comment: Sorry, I cut and pasted the wrong one from my test. I've updated the answer to include the clause that deletes lines that don't have at least 5 fields

Comment: @Williams, let me make it a bit more complex-er, I need to print the variable after the 16th variable in a line and output to a file. The 'cut' one(presented above) works perfectly, but I''m still open for easier solutions(if any !)

Comment: Just replace the 4 with 16 and it will start with the 17th variable. (I've cleaned up some more bad cut-n-pastes in my answer - I have no idea what was going on last week but the substitution was repeated for some reason.) If you mean you ONLY want the 17th variable, I'm adding a command for that too.